# How do I change the dynamic connector line color in power shell for Visio

Tags: powershell, visio

I am trying to change the color of a connector in Visio between a switch shape and a server shape. My current code is as follows:

```
$From     = $svrSwitch.MachName
$To       = $SvrSwitch.Switch
$ConnFrom = $page.Shapes | Where {$_.name -eq $From}
$ConnTo   = $page.Shapes | Where {$_.name -eq $To}
$ConnFrom.AutoConnect($ConnTo, 0, $connectorSwitch)
$arrow = $page.Shapes | Where {$_.name -eq "Dynamic Connector"} | select -First 1
$arrow.NameU = "$From-TO-$To"
$arrow.fill.ForegroundColor = 0xff0000
```

Of course I understand the last line is incorrect, I am just not sure how to proceed.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you are talking about the VisioAutomation powershell module, then you should be able to do it exactly as you wrote(that is $xx.Fill.ForegroundColor = 0xff0000). http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2009/01/22/visio-ironpython-powershell-how-to-draw-nice-diagrams-from-the-command-line.aspx. Probably this is where the confusion is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The thing to understand is that you're writing to cells in the shape's ShapeSheet, so either of these should work:

```
$arrow.CellsU("LineColor").FormulaU = "=RGB(30, 200, 30)"
$arrow.CellsU("LineColor").FormulaU = "=THEMEVAL(""AccentColor2"")"
```

and here's a complete example (no error handling) based on Visio 2013:

```
$application = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application
$documents = $application.Documents
$document = $documents.Add("NETWME_M.VSTX")
$page = $document.Pages(1)

$stencil = $application.Documents("PERIME_M.VSSX")
$switchMst = $stencil.Masters.Item("Switch")
$serverMst = $stencil.Masters.Item("Server")

$switchShp = $page.Drop($switchMst, 1, 4)
$serverShp = $page.Drop($serverMst, 3, 4)

$visAutoConnectDirNone = 0
$switchShp.Autoconnect($serverShp, $visAutoConnectDirNone)

$dynConnShp = $page.Shapes($page.Shapes.Count)

# $dynConnShp.CellsU("LineColor").FormulaU = "=RGB(30, 200, 30)"
$dynConnShp.CellsU("LineColor").FormulaU = "=THEMEVAL(""AccentColor2"")"
```

If you're not familiar with the ShapeSheet, then you might find thsi intro useful:

http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2007/10/just-for-starte.html